# Nvidia-smi showing fan speed as not available

Tags: nvidia, nvml

My machine has nvidia Tesla K20m gpu. I would like to know gpu utilzation, memory utilization, temperature and fan speed. So I have used nvidia-smi to know the details. Nvidia-smi log is as follows

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Tue Dec 10 11:06:11 2013
Driver Version                      : 319.49

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 0000:84:00.0
    Product Name                    : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                    : Disabled
    Display Active                  : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                : Enabled
    Accounting Mode                 : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : 128
    Driver Model
    Current                     : N/A
    Pending                     : N/A
Serial Number                   : 0325212069909
GPU UUID                        : GPU-8b890015-e683-4061-6596-d27716c2900b
VBIOS Version                   : 80.10.11.00.0B
Inforom Version
    Image Version               : 2081.0208.01.07
    OEM Object                  : 1.1
    ECC Object                  : 3.0
    Power Management Object     : N/A
GPU Operation Mode
    Current                     : Compute
    Pending                     : Compute
PCI
    Bus                         : 0x84
    Device                      : 0x00
    Domain                      : 0x0000
    Device Id                   : 0x102810DE
    Bus Id                      : 0000:84:00.0
    Sub System Id               : 0x101510DE
    GPU Link Info
        PCIe Generation
            Max                 : 2
            Current             : 1
        Link Width
            Max                 : 16x
            Current             : 16x
Fan Speed                       : N/A
Performance State               : P8
Clocks Throttle Reasons
    Idle                        : Active
    Applications Clocks Setting : Not Active
    SW Power Cap                : Not Active
    HW Slowdown                 : Not Active
    Unknown                     : Not Active
Memory Usage
    Total                       : 4799 MB
    Used                        : 11 MB
    Free                        : 4788 MB
Compute Mode                    : Default
Utilization
    Gpu                         : 0 %
    Memory                      : 0 %
Ecc Mode
    Current                     : Enabled
    Pending                     : Enabled
ECC Errors
    Volatile
        Single Bit
            Device Memory       : 0
            Register File       : 0
            L1 Cache            : 0
            L2 Cache            : 0
            Texture Memory      : 0
            Total               : 0
        Double Bit
            Device Memory       : 0
            Register File       : 0
            L1 Cache            : 0
            L2 Cache            : 0
            Texture Memory      : 0
            Total               : 0
    Aggregate
        Single Bit
            Device Memory       : 0
            Register File       : 0
            L1 Cache            : 0
            L2 Cache            : 0
            Texture Memory      : 0
            Total               : 0
        Double Bit
            Device Memory       : 0
            Register File       : 0
            L1 Cache            : 0
            L2 Cache            : 0
            Texture Memory      : 0
            Total               : 0
Retired Pages
    Single Bit ECC              : 0
    Double Bit ECC              : 0
    Pending                     : No
Temperature
    Gpu                         : 29 C
Power Readings
    Power Management            : Supported
    Power Draw                  : 25.44 W
    Power Limit                 : 225.00 W
    Default Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Enforced Power Limit        : 225.00 W
    Min Power Limit             : 150.00 W
    Max Power Limit             : 225.00 W
Clocks
    Graphics                    : 324 MHz
    SM                          : 324 MHz
    Memory                      : 324 MHz
Applications Clocks
    Graphics                    : 705 MHz
    Memory                      : 2600 MHz
Default Applications Clocks
    Graphics                    : 705 MHz
    Memory                      : 2600 MHz
Max Clocks
    Graphics                    : 758 MHz
    SM                          : 758 MHz
    Memory                      : 2600 MHz
Compute Processes               : None
```

How to know fan speed. Is there any plug-in? Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question seems off-topic as it is not programming-related.

Comment: Sorry. Now I made changes

Comment: Still this is probably the wrong site for this, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to find out what goes on StackOverflow. Anyway: I suppose your graphics card just doesn't have the fan speed detection hardware. Check the graphics card: If the plug that connects the fan to the board has only two wires, there's no way you can get the fan speed from the card.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [nvclock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nvclock) ? It works for my Tesla K40M.